# Is there anyway in PHP to enforce a string to be in the datetime format?

Tags: php, datetime

You can see all the accepted datetime formats [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php).

```
$timeString = 'Y-m-d';
$this->isDateTimeFormat($trimeString); // returns true
$this->isDateTimeFormat('Sponge Bob'); // returns false
```

I am not interested in solving this with regex, I already have *one* problem. But perhaps someone knows of a way to check if a string fits the requirements and then throws an exception if it doesn't?

Thanks :)

Comment: Or if you don't need to support IE <= 9, HTML5 `<input type="date">` FTW! (it shows the date picker in the users' locale, and sends it in `YYYY-MM-DD`)

Comment: @nathanhayfield This is a server-side question. What would jQuery help if the dates are stored in a DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the [`strtotime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function on the date.

If it returns anything other than 0, false, or -1, it's a good date.

If you want it in a specific format after that, just put a [`date`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) format on it.
I always add the `date` formatting because, as Boaz said, it accepts "tomorrow" or "+2 weeks" as a date.

Comment: I would only check for false (from PHP 5.1.0 and higher) or -1 for older versions. There are many values somehow equal to 0, for example.

Comment: You're right Boaz,  I made an edit that explains how to handle that.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see how `date()` is relevant. The OP wants to a validate an existing format, not reformat a value.

Comment: I would assume that the reason they want a correct date format because they are wanting to store it somewhere or do comparisons on it.   Since "yesterday" is a valid datetime format, but would fail in a comparison against a ISO 8601 date or when inserted in the database, it makes sense to reformat it.   It's still the exact same date.